# How to change language of a terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, intellisense

how can a I change a language of a terminal in VS Code? My Vs Code is in English language, but for example when I'm building a project, I have information about the problems in my local language. Quick fixes are also in local language.

Comment: you need to change the LANG environment variable. just use localectl (in case you are on linux) the terminal is just a terminal. it's not bound to language settings in vscode because it's a terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I have Win 10, I clicked "add new environment variable", but I don't know what I need to write into Name of variable and Value of variable. "LANG" and "en-US" not working ;(

Comment: then maybe install windows in english. (after all, windows is not as customizable as linux when it comes to locale)